# Calculating width of a element incorrectly

Tags: javascript, pixel

I'm trying to calculate the width of block, `id="titleText"` I am getting some luck, although it calculates incorrectly.

For example, when empty it still shows pixels (by default, it should be one), yet 18px remains in this example:

(using `onkeydown`)

[image]

(using `onkeyup`)

[image]

and...

Triggering my style logic before the number I specified, which is `585`.
[image]

My HTML is:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="serpTitle" 
onkeydown="checkTitleValue()" class="form-control" />

<p class="d-block" id="titleText"></p>
```

and the Javascript

```
function checkTitleValue() {
    var fontSize = 12;
    var measureTitle = document.getElementById("titleText");
    measureTitle.style.fontSize = fontSize;
    var height = (measureTitle.clientHeight + 1) + "px";
    var width = (measureTitle.clientWidth + 1) + "px"
    var inputTitle = document.getElementById("serpTitle").value;

    document.getElementById("titleText").innerText = inputTitle;
    document.getElementById("titlePixels").innerText = width;

        if (measureTitle.clientWidth + 1 > 585) {
            document.getElementById("titlePixels").style.color = "red";
        }
        else if (measureTitle.clientWidth + 1 < 585)
        {
            document.getElementById("titlePixels").style.color = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove onkeydown and use  ```onkeyup="checkTitleValue()"```

Comment: Try to add some debounce function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this code snippet. I don't get the point of this `measureTitle.clientWidth + 1` or `measureTitle.clientWidth + 1 < 585`
[image]
[image]

```js
const FONT_SIZE = 12;
const MAX_LENGTH = 585;
var serpTitle = document.getElementById('serpTitle');
var mesured = document.getElementById('measured');
var maxLength = document.getElementById('max-length');
var measureCont = document.getElementById('mesure-cont');
function init() {
  measureCont.style.fontSize = FONT_SIZE;
  maxLength.innerHTML = MAX_LENGTH + 'px';
  updateMesure();

}
function updateMesure() {
  measureCont.innerHTML = serpTitle.value;
  mesured.innerHTML = measureCont.clientWidth;
}
function checkTitleValue() {
  updateMesure();
  if (measureCont.clientWidth > MAX_LENGTH) {
    measured.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
    measured.style.color = null;
  }
}
init();
```

```html
<div>
 <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="serpTitle" onkeyup="checkTitleValue()" 
                class="form-control" />
       <span id="measured"></span>/<span id="max-length"></span>
 </div>
<div>
 <span style="display: inline-block" id="mesure-cont">aaaaa</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try calling the function on `keyup` instead of `keydown`.

Since each keystroke is ACTUALLY executed in the input box at `keyup`: Meaning.. (after) the key has been "pressed".

So your HTML code probably should go like:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="serpTitle" 
onkeyup="checkTitleValue()" class="form-control" />

<p class="d-block" id="titleText"></p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what I tried originally. Pretty much the same behaviour. I've edited the question with a gif for `onkeyup`

Answer (score 0):

one of the issue, regarding changing color, is that you first updating color then calculating it. So swap

```
    if (measureTitle.clientWidth > 585) {
        document.getElementById("titlePixels").style.color = "red";
    }
    else if (measureTitle.clientWidth < 585)
    {
        document.getElementById("titlePixels").style.color = null;
    }

    document.getElementById("titleText").innerText = inputTitle;
    document.getElementById("titlePixels").innerText = width;
```

Comment: And for better updates I think you can handle keyup and keydown events. For example for keydown calculate everything and onkeyup update the view.